# Thumbnail from Image Files in queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, thumbnails

I'm creating a custom CMS for blog. It's really simple, but I'm stuck at the image upload. Basically I want to make a thumbnail for not-yet uploaded images (images from file queue). Can you please tell me the steps for creating it with JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out pretty simple. We grab the image that is being uploaded, reads it as dataURL and put the result as an image source.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple />
<div id="images-container"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

and finally, **JavaScript:**

```
var images = document.getElementById('images');
var container = document.getElementById('images-container');

images.onchange = function() {
    readFiles(images.files);
}

function readFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        processFile(files[i]);
    }
}

function processFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<img src="' + reader.result + '" class="thumbnail" />';
    };
}
```